# Handling UITableCell move left (or move right) event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I  want to creat an UITableView which each cell (UITableCell) in this table can be moved left or moved right (System will be notified when user touchs down the cell and moves finger to left or right). Anybody can tell me how can i do it :) Thanks :)

I want to build a Table which each TableCell in it become a menu likes image bellow when user touch up TableCell and move finger to left or right!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would **guess** this is done by watching for the touch events, being the first responder and monitor all touch events before you send them further to the UITableView under.

I think there is a source code from Apple that shows this.. think it's called Gestures or TableView Gestures... do a search on the Apple site.

Also, do read on the UIGestureRecognizer docs from the SDK. These can be attached to a certain view, I read.

Good luck, let us know if you're successful.